# STI and uninitialized constant - after machine fixed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Okay, this is really weird...

My Macbook broke. Apple fixed it. New logic board. Now my Rails app won't run correctly on this machine.  When I got it back from the shop I pulled the latest from git, ran migrations (there weren't any) and then `foreman start` (tried just `rails s` too). Now on a certain set of routes (for a certain resourceful controller) I'm getting this:

> NameError Exception: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar

Where Bar is a subclass of Foo using single table inheritance. None of my models are namespaced. My `models` folder has no subfolders.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Bar < Foo
  ...
end
```

These models are not new. It's all been working fine for a long time before my Mac was repaired. This very minute this exact code is running without error in production at Heroku. It runs fine on my backup development machine too. I double checked that all environments are on the same versions of Rails and of Ruby.

I'm mystified. Any idea what could it be???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong about it working on my backup dev box. I mean it worked, then it didn't. This part is actually a bit foggy.

The solution was to change the parent (`Foo`) class this:

```
scope :some_scope, chain_of.other.scopes
```

To this:

```
scope :some_scope, -> { chain_of.other.scopes }
```

As it happens, the last in the chain of scopes references the child class (`Bar`) like so -- which is where the error was occurring:

```
Bar.inheritance_column
```

I have scopes besides this one in the very same class which chain other scopes without being inside of a lambda. I am still mystified by this. I solved it only by trial and error...walking backwards in small steps until I found the happy place.